# How to loop through Rails Bootstrap Carousel data slides for unknown # of slides?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've created a working Ruby on Rails Bootstrap Carousel for my rails project with a set # of images, but my website will have a variable amount of images based on user input and I want the # of slides to vary based on that # of images.  I'm new to ruby so I can't quite figure out the loop code needed to make this work... thanks for looking!

This is what the code looks like for a set # of slides (4):

```
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
```

This is my attempt at a loop based on a count of my 'outing' model (there is one image per outing which I want to loop through).  I"ll never know how many slides I'll need, one day it could be 5, next day could be 20, and day after back down to 4.

```
            <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
              <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li> 
              <%= x = @outings.count, for outingimagecount in 1..x do %> 
              <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to=#{outingimagecount)></li> 
              <% end %> 
            </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `each-with-index`:

```
<% @outings.each_with_index do |outing, i| %>
  <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to=#{i) class="#{'active' if i == 0}"></li>
<% end %>
```

Or you could do:

```
<% (1..@outings.count).each do |i| %>
```